# How to withdraw radiobutton checked in alertdialog?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have a alertdialog with radiobuttons in it. I want that the user click on one of them and it stop the alertdialog.

So there's no positif or negatif button, only a click on one of the radiobutton will close the alertdialog.

But i have no idea how to :

- close the alertdialog when the user click on a radiobutton
- withdraw the clicked radiobutton after my alertdialog is closed

Here's the code.

```
public void createAlerDialogRadioButton(String title, String[] radiobuttontitles)
{
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        RadioGroup rbg = new  RadioGroup(this);

        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        int nbbutton =  radiobuttontitles.length;           

                    // add a radiobutton to the radiogroup for each element of radiobuttontitles
        for (int i=0;i<nbbutton;i++) {
            RadioButton mrd = new RadioButton(this);
            mrd.setText(radiobuttontitles[i]);              
            rbg.addView(mrd);
            }


        // the view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams( new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(1);     
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        linearLayout.addView(rbg);

        alertDialog.setView(linearLayout);  

        alertDialog.show();

}
```

Thanks for your help.